# Data factory : type of csv column are all string, cannot change them

Tags: string, types, double, azure-data-factory

I am creating a dataflow with datafactory, and currently I am getting a csv from blob.

3 column should be consider as double. When I am doing "Import schema", here is the result :

[image]

But in Data preview :
[image]

And if I change the type to string, it is working :

[image]

Why to consider as double is impossible? I need to do a aggregation and sum the value so string are totally incompatible

I try to specify the format, it don't change anything
(here it is a test csv file with only 2 row, so no problem of having string or something like that in other rows)
thanks

Edit : what I don't understand is that the import schema understand the column as double, so why it fail in the data preview then?

Comment: Finally, after different test, I just add a function that convert my column into Decimal, it is working, so not the best thing because it adds some step but I don't want to pass more time on this shitty issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the option `Validate schema`, please don't choose it.

For example:

This is my csv data:

[image]

When click the `Validate schema`:

[image].

[image]

[image]

If we don't choose `Validate schema`, the Data Preview works well:

[image]

[image]

According my experience, if we choose the `Validate schema` option in Data Flow, Data Preview often has the error.

Hope this helps.